# Is there a way to find out the SQL that Entity Framework is creating?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an application that uses EF Core.  Is there a way for me to see what SQL is being issued with queries on the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this with [EF Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3), by increasing the logging level of database commands.

ie put this in your DbContext:

```
public static readonly ILoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
    = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AddFilter((category, level) =>
                    category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name
                    && level == LogLevel.Information)
                .AddConsole();
        });
```

And then

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory) // Warning: Do not create a new ILoggerFactory instance each time
        .UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFLogging;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");
```

Comment: I am using SQLite.  Is it also possible with SQLite?